How can I make a dynamically changing list size variable in machine code? (Assembly)
Tricky question about a a project in machine code, effectively Assembly code without labels. We are trying to find the length of a list that will change each time. The problem is, without labels, we can't change the PC offset dynamically to step back the correct amount in the memory to start iterating through the list. I'll provide the code below:
0011 0000 0000 0000 ; Starting memory location
0000 0000 0100 0011 ; List items, also below
0000 0000 0110 1110
0000 0000 0110 1011
0000 0000 0110 1101
0000 0000 0100 1111
0000 0000 0101 1110
0000 0000 0110 0011
0000 0000 0000 0000
 
1110011111110111  ; LEA R3, #-10
0101010010100000  ; AND R2, R2, #0
 
0110001011000000  ; LDR, R1, R3, #0
0000010000000110  ; BRz, #-7
0001001001000010  ; ADD R1, R1, R2
0001000001100000  ; ADD R0, R1, #0
1111000000100001  ; OUT
0001010010100001  ; ADD R2, R2, #1
0001011011100001  ; ADD R3, R3, #1
0000101111111000  ; BRnp #-8
 
1111000000100101  ; Halt

This code should take a list and:

Initialize index to zero

For each data value:

Add index to the value
Output the resulting sum as an ASCII character
Increment index
Repeat for the next data value until the terminating value is reached
Halt the program

This works, the problem is, on the line BRz #-7 we need the #-7 to change dynamically based on the size of the list initally loaded in. Any thoughts, ideas, or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Why can't you have labels if you write this in assembly and then convert it to machine code with an assembler?

It's unclear why you need that to change dynamically. That's an offset in code, does not depend on list size. Not to mention that the BRz should actually go to the Halt anyway.

Is this LC-3?  If so, there's a tag for that.  LC-3 has a register-indirect load instruction so you don't need self-modifying code to step through an array. (Unlike some toy ISAs like Marie and LMC).  Also, aren't branches relative in LC-3, not using the absolute target address? So even if a larger array appears before this code, your branch offsets are still the same even if the absolute address is different.

Usually, lists are located entirely within data, then there's code that understands the format of the data and handles it.  The code & data are kept separate.  Dynamic branches are not necessary for list handling.  We might use dynamic branches for switch and case statements, for example, which choose among different code paths, but don't need dynamic branches for lists in data.  Intermixing list items within code would be unusual as well.

Try some list handling in a language you already know and then take that to assembly.  Then your questions will be about how to do the same in assembly, such as some for-loop, or how to dereference a pointer, or do some if-statement, in assembly rather than about how to do a list algorithm in assembly.

I checked, again assuming this is LC-3 (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs310h/lectures/Lecture_10-310h.pdf), and BR instructions are PC-relative so the code is position-independent: the same sequence of machine-code bytes works the same way if loaded at different addresses.  (Unless you use jmp reg to an absolute address.)
